# Adding headers to an Android listview

Tags: android, listview

So I have a listview and I want to add different "sections" to it. I understand how addHeaderView works and it's straight forward, but is there a way to add section headers? Like let's say I have an alphabetical list, is there a way to mark the top of each section of letters? The list is dynamic though, so I won't know when/where I'll need a section header until I get to that point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These section headers are called "separators" in Android lists. To specify that given entry in the list is a separator, you must modify your Adapter to return `false` from [isEnabled](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html#isEnabled%28int%29) method for that position. It helps if you properly write the [getItemViewType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemViewType%28int%29) method, so you can have customized layout for separator entries.

Comment: Hmm. I hacked my arraylist to insert null pointers where I wanted the separators, and then just returned a simple linearlayout and textview in my getView method if the object at that position is null.

This is probably a much better way of doing it though and I'll look at this further tomorrow.

Comment: Great answer. I have spent over 4 hours trying to disable some of my items. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

i tried this example and its working fine.

http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/

it helped a lot for my task.

Comment: You can try https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/simple-section-adapter, easier than jsharkey's or commonsware's.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use http://code.google.com/p/android-section-list/ - it solves exactly this problem and adds a nice feature taken from iOS - the section header stays on screen with transparency while you scroll the section down, so you see which section you are in....